# Android app freezes when creating MediaPlayer object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I want to create a MediaPlayer object to play a sound when an event is fired. So I moved a wav sound to res/raw directory and did this to create the object:

```
this.beep = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.beep)
```

This compiles and the application runs normally, but when I open the activity where that line is typed, the screen becomes black. After running the debugger I can notice that no code is executed after that line is run.

Edit: this only happens on my physical device,on emulator it's ok.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MediaPlaer like this

```
private fun initMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        // The volume on STREAM_SYSTEM is not adjustable, and users found it
        // too loud,
        // so we now play on the music stream.
        volumeControlStream = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer!!.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        mediaPlayer!!.setOnCompletionListener(beepListener)
        val file: AssetFileDescriptor =
            resources.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.beep) as AssetFileDescriptor
        try {
            mediaPlayer!!.setDataSource(
                file.fileDescriptor,
                file.startOffset, file.length
            )
            file.close()
            mediaPlayer!!.setVolume(BEEP_VOLUME, BEEP_VOLUME)
            mediaPlayer!!.prepare()

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            mediaPlayer = null
        }
    }
}
```

And when you want to play media player call

```
mediaPlayer?.start()
```

And here is the `beepListener`

```
private val beepListener =
    OnCompletionListener { mediaPlayer ->
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(0)
    }
```

And don't forget to stop it at `onPause()`

```
mediaPlayer?.let { if (it.isPlaying) it.stop() }
```

Comment: What is this `player = null` next line: `if player == null {...` I mean.. this whole code could use some Kotlin. `mediaPlayer?.let { start() }` is equivalent to your `if` block and doesn't need to use `!!` for e.g. Or `mediaPlayer?.let { if (it.isPlaying) it.stop }`